# Syncing Content On SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, sync, synchronisation

We have a hybrid SharePoint enterprise  environment with SharePoint 2013 on-premise & SharePoint Online.

For many sites we have a requirement to keep content in-sync between some document libraries on-prem & SharePoint online because we have external vendors who need to access content that is uploaded on-premise. We would like to push out some content from on-premise sites & document libraries to sites & document libraries on SharePoint online.

How can this syncing be achieved?

Comment: Have you looked into OneDrive for Business?

Comment: Yes. I'm hoping for a way that doesn't involve another point of failure.